# Prove that $\inf(A\cap B)\geq \max [\inf(A),\inf(B)]$

Tags: real-analysis

**Question:**

Let A and B be subsets of real numbers. Prove that $\inf(A\cap B)\geq \max [\inf(A),\inf(B)]$.

**Attempt** at proof:

Let $x\in A\cap B.$

Then, $\forall (x\in A\cap B):[\inf(A) \leq x]$

and $\forall (x\in A\cap B):[\inf(B) \leq x]$.

Since any value of $x$ is at least larger than both $\inf(A)$ and $\inf(B)$,

$x\geq \max [\inf(A),\inf(B)]$

$\therefore \inf(A\cap B)\geq \max [\inf(A),\inf(B)]$

I wonder if this is starting to look like a proof for the question?

Comment: It looks like a good proof, what do you mean "a proof for the question?"

Comment: I thought my step at "Since any value of $x$ ..." was a little bit iffy, so I thought I'd ask to check.

Comment: Stating something about $inf(x)$ is sloppy and not corrct. For that line, take x alone instead:
$x\geq max\{inf(A),inf(B)\}$
Since you proved that for any $x \in A \cap B$, you can then state that the same goes is true for $inf(A \cap B)$ instead of $x$.

Comment: Thanks Fylos! I was a bit sloppy there on that line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof as written is incorrect.  You have quantified $x$ in the first line -- $x$ is an arbitrary element in $A\cap B$.  Then, in the second line, you have a new variable that you are quantifying, that is also called $x$.

Here is a simpler proof, that does not need to appeal to elements.  
$A\cap B\subseteq A$; hence $(\inf A\cap B )\ge (\inf A)$.
Similarly, $A\cap B\subseteq B$; hence $(\inf A\cap B )\ge (\inf B)$.  Since $(\inf A\cap B )$ is $\ge$ both $(\inf A)$ and $(\inf B)$,we must have $(\inf A\cap B )\ge max(\inf A,\inf B)$